# Disable Outlook Web Access Junk filtering in Exchange 2013

Tags: email, group-policy, spam, exchange-2013, outlook-web-app

By default, Outlook Web Access (OWA) in Exchange 2013 seems to move suspected junk mail to the *Junk Email* folder. This is undesirable behavior in most of my environments because we have [Barracuda Spam Filters](https://www.barracuda.com/products/spamfirewall) in place.

I'd like to accomplish the following setting globally for all existing and future users in an Exchange 2013 environment. What's the least-painful method to accomplish this?

[image]

---

I thought the Exchange shell would be magic, but running
 `Get-Mailbox | Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration -Enabled $false`

yields...

```
The Junk Email configuration couldn't be set. The user needs to sign in to Outlook Web App before they can modify
their Safe Senders and Recipients or Blocked Senders lists.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration], DataSourceOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BANANA,RequestId=479f4808-2eda-4175-8503-7b670e46c277,TimeStamp=8/4/2014 4:33:33
    PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-DataSourceOperationException] 44FC7257,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.SetMa
  ilboxJunkEmailConfiguration
    + PSComputerName        : banana
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a Transport Rule for your organization where you set the Spam Confidence Level to -1. In powerShell it would go like:

> New-TransportRule -Name 'Disable Junk filtering' -Priority '0' -SetSCL '-1'

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Exchange PowerShell:

```
$All = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
$All | foreach {Set-MailboxJunkEmailConfiguration $_.Name -Enabled $false}
```